# War record book of German soldier

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-1

I have a war record book belonging to a German man from WW1. I would like to contact his family if possible to return it. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Please look at the linked questions in the notice. If the information in the answers isn't enough to help you, please edit your question and let us know what other help you need.